# TypeScript: automatically infer function output type based on recursive input type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, recursive-type

I'm trying to write an ORM for a graph database in TypeScript. Specifically, the "find" method, which will return a list of a specific entity. Now it should also be possible to pass to this function a structure relating to the joins that should be done on the database level. Ideally, the function should automatically type these additional fields so that the client can access them. With only a single level of nesting I have been able to accomplish this, though it would be awesome to make it work with multiple levels.

My (already working) solution for only one nesting level is as follows:

```
interface IDocumentModel {
  _id?: string;
}

type JoinParams<T extends Record<string, IDocumentModel>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    model: DocumentModel<T[K]>;
  };
};

type JoinResult<T, U> = (U & {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K][];
})[];

class DocumentModel<T extends IDocumentModel> {
  async find<X extends Record<string, IDocumentModel>>(
    filter?: Partial<T>,
    hydrate?: JoinParams<X>,
  ): Promise<JoinResult<X, T>> {
    // TODO: implementation
  }
}

const ParentModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, parentField: string }>();
const ChildModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, childField: string }>();

const results = await ParentModel.find(
  { _id: 'abc' },
  {
    children: {
      model: ChildModel,
    },
  },
);

console.log(results[0].parentField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].childField);
```

Now the challenge is to extend it to two levels, or even better an arbitrary amount of levels. This is my work in progress for two levels of nesting:

Here is my current solution surrounding the problem.

```
interface IDocumentModel {
  _id?: string;
}

type JoinParams<
  T extends
    | Record<string, IDocumentModel>
    | Record<string, Record<string, IDocumentModel>>,
> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    model: T extends Record<string, Record<string, IDocumentModel>>
      ? DocumentModel<T[K]['parent']>
      : T extends Record<string, IDocumentModel>
      ? DocumentModel<T[K]>
      : never;
    hydrate?: T extends Record<string, Record<string, IDocumentModel>>
      ? JoinParams<Omit<T[K], 'parent'>>
      : never;
  };
};

type JoinResult<
  T extends
    | Record<string, IDocumentModel>
    | Record<string, Record<string, IDocumentModel>>,
  U,
> = (U & {
  [K in keyof T]: T extends Record<string, Record<string, IDocumentModel>>
    ? JoinResult<Omit<T[K], 'parent'>, T[K]['parent']>
    : T extends Record<string, IDocumentModel>
    ? T[K][]
    : never;
})[];

class DocumentModel<T extends IDocumentModel> {
  async find<X extends Record<string, Record<string, IDocumentModel>>>(
    filter?: Partial<T>,
    hydrate?: JoinParams<X>,
  ): Promise<JoinResult<X, T>> {
    // TODO: implementation
  }
}

const ParentModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, parentField: string }>();
const ChildModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, childField: string }>();
const GrandChildModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, grandChildField: string }>();

const results = await ParentModel.find(
  { _id: 'abc' },
  {
    children: {
      model: ChildModel,
      hydrate: {
        grandchildren: {
          model: GrandChildModel,
        },
      },
    },
  },
);

console.log(results[0].parentField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].childField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].grandchildren[0].grandChildField);
```

When I try my test cases

```
console.log(results[0].parentField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].childField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].grandchildren[0].grandChildField);
```

I do not get any autocomplete beyond `results[0].parentField`. This means, the IDE does not suggest `results[0].children` as being a valid field anymore.

I hope this is enough information, though I'd be happy to clarify more if unclear.

Comment: You're going to have to switch things so that `hydrate`'s type is a plain type parameter and not a recursive mapped type, and then compute from it. But right now this doesn't look like a [mre] because I'm sure you don't need everything here to demonstrate the issue (e.g., your `edgeDirection`, `edgeCollectionName`, and all references to `"parent"` seem to just be complicating things and not being used here).  Could you pare this down to the smallest code necessary to demo your problem? Any answer here is probably going to look like a rewrite and not a tweak so it would help to slim this down.

Comment: Like, perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvQ8Bm) is what you need?  If so I could write that up as an answer (if you'd [edit] your code to be appropriately slimmed down). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I took out the unncessary details from the question, I hope it makes it more clear. The reason I included `edgeDirection` and `edgeCollectionName` originally was to demonstrate why `hydrate` needed to be an object at each level, and it wouldn't suffice to just pass the model directly. With your linked answer I get exactly the typing I was looking for on the output, thank you so much! So you can go ahead and formulate it as an answer.

Comment: There are only two minor issues, perhaps they are solvable as well. First, the input type to `find()` is not as strict anymore. I could pass `modl: entityChildModel` instead of `model: entityChildModel` and it would still work. The other issue is that within the `join()` method, `hydrate['children'].hydrate?['grandchildren']` is of type `string[]`, even though I would expect to the be an object with a `model`

Comment: If I try `modl` in my code [I get a compile error](https://tsplay.dev/mpKvaN) so I don't see what you mean.  What `join()` method are you talking about? I don't understand your two problems so I'm not sure how to proceed here.  Can I write an answer and not worry about whatever this followup issue is?  Or can you clarify the issue, hopefully with some sort of [mre] I can use to see the problem?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your time! When I said `join()` I meant the `find()` method, it was just an older name of the function, sorry for the confusion. I have commented the example you gave [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3oajm). I wasn't able to reproduce the `string[]` issue anymore, instead the fields are typed as `any` within the function (but that's not a big deal). The more pressing issue is that the client could input `modl` accidentally. If this is not solvable, no worries though, you have already helped a lot!

Comment: So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXy2VN) fix the issue?  If so I'll proceed with this version.

Comment: Yes, that was the missing piece, this solves both problems actually! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript isn't clever enough to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument `T` from a `hydrate` value of type `JoinParams<T>` when `JoinParams` is a recursive [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  The more complicated a type function `F<T>` is, the less likely the compiler can infer `T` from it.  Instead of even trying that, you should refactor so that the `hydrate` parameter is of a type very simply related to the generic type parameter you're trying to infer.  The simplest relationship is identity: if you're trying to infer `H` from `hydrate`, then make `hydrate` of type `H` directly.  Then you can *compute* your other types from `H`.

One approach looks like:

```
class DocumentModel<M extends IDocumentModel> {
  declare t: M;
  async find<H extends Hydrate>(
    filter?: Partial<M>,
    hydrate?: H,
  ): Promise<Find<M, H>> {
    hydrate?.children.hydrate?.grandchildren.model;
    return null!
  }
}

type Hydrate = {
  [k: string]: SubHydrate<IDocumentModel, Hydrate>
}

interface SubHydrate<M extends IDocumentModel, H extends Hydrate> {
  model: DocumentModel<M>,
  hydrate?: H
}    

type Find<M extends IDocumentModel, H extends Hydrate> = Array<M & {
  [K in keyof H]: H[K] extends 
    SubHydrate<infer M extends IDocumentModel, infer H extends Hydrate> ? Find<M, H> : never
}>
```

Here we are [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `H` to `Hydrate`, a type that should hopefully allow valid values and disallow invalid ones.  `Hydrate` is written in terms of `SubHydrate`, which is itself generic in the model type `M` and a nested `Hydrate` type `H`.  So `H` should be easily inferred from the call to `find()`.

Then the return type of `find()` is `Find<M, H>`, which does the work of converting `hydrate`'s and `model`'s types to the expected output type.  It recursively descends through `H`, inferring the nested `M` and `H` types from it.

Let's see it in action:

```
const ParentModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, parentField: string }>();
const ChildModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, childField: string }>();
const GrandChildModel = new DocumentModel<{ _id?: string, grandChildField: string }>();

const results = await ParentModel.find(
  { _id: 'abc' },
  {
    children: {
      model: ChildModel,
      hydrate: {
        grandchildren: {
          model: GrandChildModel,
        },
      },
    },
  },
);

console.log(results[0].parentField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].childField);
console.log(results[0].children[0].grandchildren[0].grandChildField);
```

Looks good.  Everything behaves as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMEsB2NhQBmAhgMbBwCSAIhKQK4C2weAshACbAA2iGccAPpYOAfgBccAM4wouAOYBuDGkxqYATzAUAEho5Ri+OAF4+6AQG0A1pJlyc8gLqSAyvQBGeg0eAAeGjomFhh2Lm4AGjhvQ3wAPhUMbDwCEnI4dy99WP9WOFB8HA4pKloGZjZOHiidfJBC4ujs3zjzAUYq7kky4Mrwv1Y4iP44AAtm-AloxLVSbmIpEp6K0M6BuoaSwPKQsJ5WhBGuOeIoChhJVmULOAWNHFI4QlwOP1qClkaYloAKEYFntx8FApgAFU4wLDEbgDIb-MYTYBTHTDG4ASkkoKgEEYWCk-gAYi8BjU4gd4eMfJMAHSkUZYbgGFjUyk5UTU+SGIp0hlMnDUjrha4CARnGD0KA4OA4ejcbgAQhGqlUGE02jgRKK6w+RS2y12nRqG0+JW+8VMcAAglBDBp1gAyNpwSwAaTguDg1mAGgghGiLmirqcxt1cHhmTN-lwhAIcDyOsa216q3CUWjsfe9RNTSpwFaog1xNYpLgkhwwAAbgQVAlZhAcDI4OCzn0eBbywB3OD61swpDCMR2WQKKJgU4hIk8DhDhzyFBxH5o66keuNgDC9MZe14Zk73aCK23fn7Iim9hHcB5jMnjJnCnni+Xq-gAHEuRwN7zt+3gF2eymeGPIRTzvRwok5Ygik-a8sCnUC52QBclySdAVwbeAzikWUYBKMxiA7YgsHgZsDXCalniKP4bhPac4AAcmIDxSDolBUQEQ4bgEK8+UkDiRRFQUeEkaCOG3Nj+IRXNePhfiIO5TceKdCSBM6SQ30gj8FLEmSRWQcT+L0+FDJuYzkLrBsIG4YBqW4CB5B+TDsKkSwAAYnGpMcWxgG8ODMtCpEs6zbPsxygWctzaQUltXPc7ifL81dApsuyHOALCwpiyLeWiiK5I4bicvcvKRPi64MCAA)

Comment: Thanks again for the solution and also the accompanying explanation, which will help me with future problems, I'm sure!